# Como desabilitar controles com JQuery ao carregar a página

Tags: jquery

Incluir o Código JS abaixo para desabilitar os campos quando o checkbox estiver marcado. Porém, quando eu carrego a página com ele marcado os campos precisam estar desabilitados, e o comando só os desabilita quando ocorre o click.
Como posso desabilitar os controles (textbox) com o carregamento da página?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#chkContaProvisoria').click(function ()
        {
            if (this.checked)
            {
                $('#DadosConta_Conta_DtValidade').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#DadosConta_Conta_Numero').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            else
            {
                $('#DadosConta_Conta_DtValidade').removeAttr("disabled")
                $('#DadosConta_Conta_Numero').removeAttr("disabled")
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Apresentação do formulário com os campos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer dessa forma

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#chkContaProvisoria').click(function ()
    {
        desabilitaTextBox();
    });

    //chama a função apos o carregamento da pagina, 
    //se o checkbox estiver marcado ele desabilita o campo.
    desabilitaTextBox();

});

function desabilitaTextBox() {
    if ($('#chkContaProvisoria').is(':checked')) {
         $('#DadosConta_Conta_DtValidade').attr("disabled", "disabled");
         $('#DadosConta_Conta_Numero').attr("disabled", "disabled");
     } else {
         $('#DadosConta_Conta_DtValidade').removeAttr("disabled");
         $('#DadosConta_Conta_Numero').removeAttr("disabled");
     }
}
```

Comment: Top.. Funcionou.. valew